# Chef Apache2 with mod php cookbook from Supermarket - getting no such file or directory

Tags: php, ruby, apache, chef-infra, cookbook

looking for a bit of guidance

I'm trying to use the Apache2 cookbook from the Chef Supermarket. I'm creating a virtualhost with the following code:

```
#Install shop
directory '/var/www/html/shop/' do
  owner 'www-data'
  group 'www-data'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

#Configures Apache Site for shop 
web_app "shop" do
   template 'web_app.conf.erb'
   server_name "www.xyz.com.au"
   server_aliases ["www.xyz.com.au"]
   docroot "/var/www/html/shop"
   options '-Indexes'
   cookbook 'apache2'
   allow_override
end
```

This works fine and i can connect to the http server ok. But when I invoke mod_php:

```
apache_module "mod_php" do
  enable true
end
```

I get the following error. Am I doing something wrong enabling PHP with this cookbook?

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 121 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_php.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mod_php.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mod_php.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So i'm not sure what to do on this one, but i thought i'd ask and see if anyone has experience in using this cookbook?
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apache2#readme

And i'd be interested if anyone is aware of how to pass php config variables into the php.ini. I cant see it from this cookbook?

thanks,

-nat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs for this cookbook indicate, the recipe will attempt to infer various pieces of information based on the name that you pass in. In your case, this is `mod_php`. This defaults to looking for a filename of `mod_mod_php`. You can provide a different filename based on what you need, which might look something like this.

```
apache_module "php7" do
  filename "libphp7.so"
end
```

I would first check what modules are installed in the `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`. You may have a different version of php, or need to install the appropriate module first.

**Edit:**
It's important to also change the first line from `apache_module "mod_php" do` to `apache_module "php7" do`. The default name for the Module is inferred as follows:

> identifier - String to identify the module for the LoadModule directive. Not typically needed, defaults to #{name}_module

Alternatively, you can set the identifier to 'php7' (or whatever the name of the module is).

Comment: hi Mangesh, thanks for the reply, i really appreciate it. I have confirmed that this is the right file and its located: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so but i am now receiving this Error:
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_php.load: Can't locate API module structure `mod_php_module' in file /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so

any ideas how to address this?

Comment: @Nathan Similar to the previous issue this seems like a naming convention issue. The cookbook defaults the identifier to `#{name}_module` while I believe the name of the module is actually `php7_module`. You can similarly override this:
    `identifier "php7_module"`
or change the name on the first line:
    `apache_module "php7" do`

Comment: Thank you Mangesh! This was super helpful, I really appreciate it!!